# Is the Name Allah actually Allah Himself?

Tags: allah

Is there a difference between the Name Allah and Allah Himself? How do you verbally express the relationship between the Holy Name Allah and Allah Himself?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) will help?

Answer (score 1):

You can discuss Allah (ﷻ)  in terms of His Essence v. His Attributes (in which case His Name is not 'Him' per say)... but ultimately His Attributes are not separate from Him. They are of Him [same as His Words which He speaks]. Thus, the name 'Allah' (as with any of His 99 Names) is not separate from Allah Himself (His Being). This is the Islamic conclusion. And Islamic scholars have discussed this topic as it is from the fundamentals of Islam (Knowing Allah/Tawheed). You may do some research into His Essence v. Attributes and these discussions will definitely come up.

Summary: **Allah is God. His Name is His Attribute. His Attributes are not separate from Him.**